# How can I resolve "resolution Unsuitable resolution declared for angular" in bower install?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, docker, npm, bower

I am currently migrating an old internal application onto Kubernetes. When building the docker image, specifically at `RUN bower --allow-root install`, I face this error:

```
bower angular                                    resolution Unsuitable resolution declared for angular: 1.6.6
bower                                             ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
The command '/bin/sh -c bower --allow-root install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the dependencies being outdated. [Here](https://gist.github.com/DominicCabral/4aad84780638cb56db47e0140f4b7a28) is the `bower.json` and `Dockerfile` for reference.